# How do i split string contain parentheses into array and remain the substring in parentheses in shell script

Tags: bash, shell, sed

I have a string like this:

```
a1="a,b,c,(d,e),(f,g)";
```

How to get the array like

```
arr=["a","b","c","d,e","f,g"];
```

I want to replace the comma between parentheses with some other character and revert it after having converted into array

But i do not know how to replace only the comma between parentheses;
how can this be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try following [bash](/questions/tagged/bash) script where I parse the string using regular expression. It's awkward for me but seems to work:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

unset arr
a1="a,b,c,xxx(d,e),sdf(f,g)"

## The regular expression does an alternation between
## a pair of parens followed by an optional comma "\([^\)]+\)(,?)"
## or any characters followed by a comma or end of line "[^,]+(,|$)"
## After that I save all the rest of the string to match it in
## following iterations.
while [[ $a1 =~ ([^\(,]*\([^\)]+\)(,?)|[^,]+(,|$))(.*) ]]; do

    ## BASH_REMATCH keeps grouped expressions. The first one
    ## has the data extracted between commas. This removes the
    ## trailing one.
    elem="${BASH_REMATCH[1]%,}"

    ## Remove opening paren, if exists one.
    elem="${elem/\(/}"

    ## Remove trailing paren, if exists one.
    elem="${elem%)}"

    ## Add element to an array.
    arr+=("$elem")

    ## Use the string left (fourth grouped expression in
    ## the regex) to continue matching elements.
    a1="${BASH_REMATCH[4]}"
done

printf "%s\n" "${arr[@]}"
```

Running it like:

```
bash script.sh
```

It yields:

```
a
b
c
xxxd,e
sdff,g
```

Comment: Though I am not very clear for it, it does work. i will study it later. Thanks

Comment: @user2256235: I've edited the script to add comments. I hope now to be easier to understand.

Comment: Frankly speaking, I did not use some regular expression before. When I am trying to make it work for the string likes "a,b,c,xxx(d,e),sdf(f,g)", I failed.
    $a1 =~ ([a-z]*\([^\)]+\)(,?)|[^,]+(,|$))(.*)
 Could you tell me how should i do. Many thanks

Comment: @user2256235: Why are there characters just before a pair of parens? What output do you expect of that?

Comment: In fact, the string I am operating likes a,b,c,xxx(d,e),sdf(f,g) and there are some characters before a pair of parens. And I'm sorry that i did not realize the trouble it brings.

Comment: @user2256235: Do you know what is a problem with regular expressions? That a seemingly insignificant change in the input may involve a big change of the regex. I've updated the answer but think about it for following questions. Try to give complete input cases because we usually don't like to repeat the job.

Answer (score 1):

#### GNU sed parser

```
sed 's/,/\",\"/g;s/(\(.\)\"/\1/g;s/\"\(.\))/\1/g;s/^\w\+=\"/arr=[\"/;s/;/];/'
```

Comment: There is a little error, output is : `arr=[a","b","c","d,e","f,g"];` But this can be easily fixed using `arr=["...` in the last expression. But however, nice answer! :)

Answer (score 0):

Write a parser! :D

I have no idea how to do this in bash, but I can show you how to do it in PHP (should be transferable to other languages).

```
$str = "a,b,c,(d,e),(f,g)";
$out = array();
$current_token = "";
$open_brackets = 0;
$length = strlen($str)
for ($i = 0; $i < $length; $i += 1) {
    $chr = $str[$i];
    if ($chr === "(") {
        $open_brackets += 1;
    } else if ($chr === ")") {
        $open_brackets -= 1;
    } else if ($open_brackets === 0 && $chr === ",") {
        $out[] = $current_token; // push token value to out
        $current_token = "";
    } else {
        $current_token .= $chr;
    }
}
if (strlen($current_token) > 0) {
    $out[] = $current_token; // dont forget the last one
}
var_dump($out); // ["a","b","c","d,e","f,g"]
```

Untested, but this is the outline. Keep track of number of brackets and only when the brackets are matched should `,` be interpretted as a delimiter.